# unsure where to install grub on hardware RAID10 after upgrading ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2

After upgrading packages on a Ubuntu 14.04 system, the grub-pc configuration tool asks me where to install GRUB.

- /dev/sda (500107 MB; ST9500530NS)
- /dev/sdb (500107 MB; ST9500530NS)
- /dev/sdc (500107 MB; ST9500620NS)
- /dev/sdd (500107 MB; ST9500530NS)
- /dev/sde (500107 MB; ST9500530NS)
- /dev/dm-0 (1973860 MB; data1--vg-root)

I did not configure this server, but I do know it is has hardware RAID configuration.

Where should grub be installed?

Based on comments:

```
sudo pvs
[sudo] password for coen:
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda5  pindi-vg lvm2 a--  697.88g 45.96g
```

and

```
for szDisk in $(ls /dev/sd?); do echo "$szDisk"; dd if="$ 
                    szDisk" bs=1 count=4 skip=392; done

/dev/sda
GRUB4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4 bytes (4 B) copied, 0.0139631 s, 0.3 kB/s
```

I think this suggests I should choose /dev/sda to install grub ?

Comment: Yep... not raid10 and not hardware either.  What does `sudo pvs` show?

Comment: That's not a RAID 10: the numbers don't add up. Please run the following in a root prompt `for szDisk in $(ls /dev/sd?); do echo "$szDisk"; dd if="$szDisk" bs=1 count=4 skip=392; done` Then [edit] your question and provide the output.